# Replace text in document and make clickable jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my page i have randomly the word -FORM-. I want to replace the word with both dashes for a div that is clickable. Currently i have some code that works but its not clickable.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $formContainer = $('<div id="get-form">This is my div container container</div>').html();

    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('-FORM-', $formContainer);

    $('#get-form').click(function(){
        alert('Click!')
    })
});
```

Comment: `$('<div id="get-form">This is my div container container</div>').html();` is just a very complex and inefficient way to say `'<div id="get-form">This is my div container container</div>'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.html()` gets the inner html of the element, in this case just the inner text of your element. It does not get the outer html. You would need to use `$formContainer[0].outerHTML` to get your full html string.

Though in this case you do not even need that as there is no reason to even wrap your html string into a jQuery object since you never use the jQuery object afterwards. Just use your html string in the replace:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('-FORM-', '<div id="get-form">This is my div container container</div>');
```

Comment: Patrick do you have a small example for me please? I learn bether from examples.

Comment: I mean with the outerHTML. Your line of code works fine but doesnt get the part for the outerHTML. Sorry, im dutch

Comment: @DonnyvanV `.replace('-FORM-',$formContainer[0].outerHTML)` would be the way to do it using the jQuery object. But like I said there is no point in doing that way since its inefficient.

Comment: Thank you Patrick. Now i get it :) Im using the first method you told me, works great. I also learned now how to use it with a jQ object. Thanks for the short lesson :)

Comment: @DonnyvanV http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/9sz1x7fz/4/  I think it will be helpful for you